# GPRBuild does not compile C files

Tags: c, ada, gnat, gprbuild

I upgraded to GNAT Community 2018 (everything worked fine with GNAT GPL 2017). I have this project file:

```
with "opengl";

library project OpenGL.Soil is
   for Library_Name use "SoilAda";

   for Languages use ("ada", "c");

   for Source_Dirs use ("src/soil");

   -- snip compiler config
end OpenGL.Soil;
```

Now in `src/soil`, there are a couple of `.ads` and `.adb` files as well as `.h` and `.c` files. Previously, this project file compiled all of them and linked them together just fine when used. Since GNAT Community 2018, this file only compiles the Ada sources, not the C sources.

Things I have tried:

- Ensured that GCC coming with GNAT Community still supports compiling C. Yes it does.
- Explicitly defined `Naming` package setting `Spec_Suffix` and `Implementation_Suffix` for C to the respective file endings.
- Explicitly specified `Source_Files` and put all Ada and C files in it.

No matter what I did, GPRBuild, when invoked, will not compile the C files (resulting in linker errors). There is no error or warning output regarding the C files even if they are explicitly specified.

How can I make GPRBuild compile the C files again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reason was that there were still 32bit object files from the previous compiler lying around. GPRBuild did not re-compile those but also didn't try and link them (which would have failed), calling `gprclean -r` on the project and compiling again fixed it.

Comment: Another fun problem is having different units depending on scenario variable settings; gprclean won’t remove objects that wouldn’t be in the current scenario. `rm .build/*`

Comment: @SimonWright To work around that I specify a unique object directory for each scenario variable.